# Move list item to new parent without flickering

Tags: reactjs

Imagine the following list:

- Managing Director

  - Sales Director
  - IT Director

    - Technical Lead

      - Software Developer
      - Support Technician
  - HR Department

    - HR Officer

      - HR Assistant 1
      - HR Assistant 2

It's backed by a state in the form of:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Managing Director",
        children: [
            {
                id: 2,
                text: "Sales Director"
            }
            ...
        ]
    }
    ...
]
```

Now I want to indent `Support Technician`. I would modify the state array to remove the item from the `Technical Lead` parent & add it to the `Software Developer` parent. The problem is, that React first deletes it, which causes all items below it to jump one line up, and then in the next frame adds it again to the new parent, which pushes those items a line down again. This appears as a flicker. It doesn't happen every time (sometimes react manages to render both in the same frame), but often enough it happens and is very distracting.

The state is modified in a way, that the parent passes its state callback `setState` down to its children. In this case, the initial state of the `Technical Lead` node looks like:

```
{
    id: 4,
    text: "Technical Lead",
    children: [
        {
            id: 5,
            text: "Software Developer"
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            text: "Support Technician"
        }
    ]
}
```

As obvious from the state, every node renders all its children recursively.
After the indention, the state is modified to the following:

```
{
    id: 4,
    text: "Technical Lead",
    children: [
        {
            id: 5,
            text: "Software Developer",
            chiilderen: [
                {
                    id: 6,
                    text: "Support Technician"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I were to this without React and instead with regular DOM APIs, I would **move** the node to the new parent with something like `insertBefore()`. React on the other hand unmounts & remounts the node.

Below is a simplified example of my "Node" component, which renders the list:

```
const Node = ({data, setSiblings}) => {
    const [children, setChildren] = useState(data.children)
    
    function indent() {
        setSiblings(siblings => {
            // const prevSibling = find the item in the state array
            // const thisNode = {id, text, children}
            const newPrevSibling = {...prevSibling, children: [thisNode]}
            const siblingsWithout_ThisNode = deleteFromArray(siblings, thisNodeIndex)
            // updateAtIndex() returns a new array with the modification (immutable)
            return updateAtIndex(siblingsWithout_ThisNode, prevSiblingIndex, newPrevSibling)
        })
    }
    
    const childNodes = children?.map(child =>
        <Node data={child} setSiblings={setChildren} key={child.id}/>
    )
    return (
        <li>
            <div>{data.text}</div>
            {childNodes ? <ul>{childNodes}</ul> : null}
        </li>
    )
}
```

The `indent()` function is triggered by a `Tab` press, but I didn't include the key handler logic here

Comment: I can provide a video/gif if needed, but since it's not that easy with Stackoverflow, I didn't include it for now

Comment: How do you modify the state?

Comment: As said, via the `setState` callback. This part works fine though. Doing things like adding itmes to the list (also added via setState()) works like expected. The indention functionality works as well, only the flickering is really annoying

Comment: So do you have two calls to setState? One for removing the item and one for adding it in a new position?

Comment: Can you share the code that modifies the state?

Comment: I actually tried both, doing it in one call (passing the recursively modifed state) and in seperate ones. The result is the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240844/discussion-between-serhii-holinei-and-john-smith).

Comment: @JohnSmith, Could you upload your code to CodeSandbox?

Comment: I edited my answer with a simplified example of my react component. If that's not clear enough, I will upload the whole code to CodeSandbox, but I think it's clearer this way

Comment: @JohnSmith I had to delete my answer because after your comments I no longer thought it held true. I'm also unsure about the exact problem with your implementation and don't want to clutter answer space with speculation. Your recursive solution is very clever, but it also might be problematic (this is the part I'm unsure of) for React and its diffing algo. You also copy props into local state which is an anti-pattern (https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state
).

Comment: @kamil_k The anti-pattern describes, that the props would override the state, which is not the case in my case, since `useState` is only called when the component is mounted, not on subsequent rerenders. I use the initial prop as initialization of the node (its children), but then it can gain/lose children, since the list it editable (the user can add/remove items). I left this part out, since I didn't think it was relevant & would blow up the code

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution to this problem directly, but I switched to using MST (MobX-State-Tree) for state management now and it worked with it (didn't flicker anymore - seemingly, both the unmounting & remounting of the component happen in the same frame now).

Below is a CodeSandbox with the MST implementation. When clicking e.g. on the `Support Technician` node, you can press `Tab` to indent and `Shift + Tab` to outdent (you have to click again, since it loses focus)
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-keldysh-17e9h?file=/src/App.js

While this doesn't answer my question directly, it helped solve the problem semantically (it's better than nothing).

Comment: I'm still interested in why the flickering happend with my original solution. I therefore won't mark it as answered.